# What backup tool should I use for easy incremental backups?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, incremental-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to provide proper backups for multiple Linux based servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2262/how-to-provide-proper-backups-for-multiple-linux-based-servers)

I want to do nightly backups of the whole system and be able to rollback to any of last 7 days. And, it must be incremental backups. What tool should I use? The tutorials I've read about rsync tell only how to store *latest* incremental backup and I need last 7.

Comment: What media do you plan to backup to? Tape? NFS? Disk? SMB?

Comment: I plan to backup to disk and also upload backups to ftp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/)? It uses rsync for the incremental backup, but gives you as many snapshots as you want (and have space for).

Similar to *jcisio*'s suggestion, but fully packaged.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a backup solution that uses small disk space.

With rsync and hard links you can create backup and roll back to any previous snapshot. Only files which are modified use disk space. You can even create 365 snapshots and roll back to any of them, and it does not uses too much disk space (supposing that your files does not change much: if everyday you replace your files with completely different files, then there is really no efficient incremental backup solution).

A helpful tutorial is http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Answer (score 1):

If you are un ubuntu why don't use integrated [SimpleBackupSuite](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite) ? Is simple and easy to use .

Otherwise you can do wat you want with bacula but is not easy to use as SimpleBackupSuite.

Comment: I'm using server edition and don't have a gui. I know about bacula but it's way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an inexpensive robust commercial package that works well on standalone systems and can do *bare-metal recovery*, you can try [Cactus Lone-Tar](http://www.cactus.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=53). It uses a variety of transports and can handle multiple types of destinations. Cataloging and Master/Selective/Incremental backups are very easy to schedule and maintain.